# Facing proxy issues while scraping using Python as my programming language

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy

I am currently working on a web scraping project and I'm encountering proxy-related issues. I need assistance in resolving these issues and would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.
Here's a brief overview of my setup and the problem I'm facing:

- I'm using Python as my programming language and utilizing popular libraries like BeautifulSoup and Requests.
- I have a list of websites that I need to scrape, but I'm facing difficulties when trying to make requests through a proxy server.
- I have the necessary proxy server details (IP address: 123.45.67.89 Port: 8080, user:jacoba, Password: jacoba123), but I'm unsure how to integrate them into my scraping code to make successful requests.

**To provide context, here's a simplified version of my scraping code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Proxy server details
proxy_ip = '123.45.67.89'
proxy_port = '808'
proxy_username = 'jacoba'
proxy_password = 'jacoba123'

# Here's how you can integrate the proxy server details into your scraping code
proxies = {
    'http': f'http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}',
    'https': f'https://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}'
}

def scrape_website(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
        # Additional scraping logic using BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        # Rest of your scraping code
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Example usage:
website_url = 'https://www.example.com'
scrape_website(website_url)
```

Could someone please guide me on how to modify the code to incorporate the proxy server details correctly? Any suggestions, code snippets, or examples that demonstrate the proper usage of proxies in web scraping scenarios would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Facing proxy issues while scraping: Need help resolving and including relevant code